# scrollTop = scrollHeight on a class instead of id

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ok so this is what I am trying to use

`$(".shouts").scrollTop = $(".shouts").scrollHeight;`

Which I believe is correct when using classes instead of id's but this doesn't work, and I think it is because of the code above it which is

```
function refreshShouts() {
    var refreshRate = 5000; // time in milliseconds
    var cacheBuster = (new Date).getTime();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        url: "php/getShouts.php",
        data: {op: 'tick', time: cacheBuster},
        error: function() { alert('An error occured! Try again.'); },
        success: function(xml){
            if($('shout', xml).size() > 0) {
                $('shout', xml).each(function(id){
                    var nickname = $('nickname', this).text();
                    var message = $('message', this).text();
                    var date = $('date', this).text();
                    var cssClass = 'shoutRow1';
                    if((id%2)/10 == 0)
                        cssClass = 'shoutRow';
                    var shoutRow = '<div id="'+cssClass+'"><span id="nickname">'+nickname+' <span id="date">('+date+')</span>: </span><span id="shoutedMessage">'+message+'</span></div>';
                    if(id == 0)
                        $('#shoutsContainer').empty().removeClass().addClass('shouts').html(shoutRow);
                    else
                        $('#shoutsContainer').removeClass().addClass('shouts').append(shoutRow);
                });
            } else {
                $('#shoutStatus').empty().addClass('shoutError').html($('error', xml).text());
                $('#shoutsContainer').empty().removeClass().addClass('noShouts').html('Shouts will be displayed here!');
            }
            $(".shouts").scrollTop = $(".shouts").scrollHeight;
        }
    });
    setTimeout('refreshShouts()', refreshRate);
}
```

maybe because it creates it, I am not sure.. normally I am using div id's instead of classes for this but I was hoping to get this to work.

Comment: This will help: `$(".shouts").first().scrol...`. Grabs the first one of the elements as a jQuery object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with IDs because there's only one. But with classes, how does it know which one is which?

Try this:

```
$(".shouts").each(function() {this.scrollTop = this.scrollHeight;});
```

Comment: .each isn't needed unless he wants it to scroll to everyone with that class, which won't be visible by user. It'll just appear to go to last one. He'd be better off using `.last()` or `.first()`. +1 anyway for giving an answer. Happy Holidays all!